# ERROR Aborting because rootful Docker (/var/run/docker.sock) is running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I want to setup **rootless docker** based on docker official documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/). All docker service has been stopped, however when running below command:

`dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install`

I got below error:

> [ERROR] Aborting because rootful Docker (/var/run/docker.sock) is running and accessible. Set --force to ignore.

Is it safe if i'm using `--force` option?

Answer (score 12):

try this command
**sudo systemctl disable --now docker.service docker.socket**

then reboot you system

Comment: Any way to avoid reboot?